# Codeigniter Error Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: codeigniter

I am getting error of " Trying to get property of non-object" my controller code is

```
public function productDetails($pro_name,$product_id) {
$data['prodRating'] = $this->ProductsModel -> get_one($product_id);
  $this->load->view('home',$data);  
}
```

Model Code

```
function get_one($pro_id){
$query= $this->db->select('ratingid, pro_item_id, pro_total_points, pro_total_rates, proid ')
          ->from('tblproducts')
          ->where('proid',$pro_id)
          ->join('tblprorating','tblprorating.pro_item_id = tblproducts.proid','left')
          ->get();
 return $query->result();                
 }
```

view code

```
 <span dir="ltr" class="inline">

            <input id="input-<?=$prodRating->proid ?>" name="rating"
                <?php if ($prodRating->$pro_total_rates > 0 or $prodRating->pro_total_points > 0) { ?>
                    value="<?php echo $prodRating->pro_total_points / $prodRating->pro_total_rates ?>"
                <?php } else { ?>
                    value="0"
                <?php } ?>
                <?php if ($this->session->userdata('userid') == false) { ?>
                    data-disabled="false"
                <?php } else { ?>
                    data-disabled="<?= $rated ?>"
                <?php } ?>
                   class="rating "
                   min="0" max="5" step="0.5" data-size="xs"
                   accept="" data-symbol="&#xf005;" data-glyphicon="false"
                   data-rating-class="rating-fa">
        </span>
```

What is problem in my code if i use foreach loop then i can solve my problem. But in this code i not want to use the foreach loop. I want to access the fields of database. but i am getting error.

Answer (score 1):

Return `return $query->row()` for single item. `result()` is for many. Further you should check `num_rows()` before attempting to access the result object/array and handle 0 rows properly as it is good practice.

In this case:

```
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    return $query->row();
}
return false;
```

Comment: thanks for  solving the problem. i used  your code to solve this problem.